# How to get final redirected url after all redirection of tracking links?

Tags: php, curl

I want to get final redirected url after all redirection in php. I used lots of function and code searched from web but no one is correct for some tracking url.

Here is my url : http://performance.ikoo.com/geo_tracking_redirect.html?a=CD441&program_id=1304274

It finally redirects to : https://www.shopandship.com/my-shopandship/profile.aspx

How can i get the final redirect url for such type of url.
please help.

Answer (score 3):

Just Try with this.

```
        <?php


    function getLastEffectiveUrl($url)
    {
        // initialize cURL
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        ));

        // execute the request
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        // extract the target url
        $redirectUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        curl_close($curl);

        return $redirectUrl;
    }

    $url="http://performance.ikoo.com/geo_tracking_redirect.html?a=CD441&program_id=1304274";

    $lastEffectiveUrl = getLastEffectiveUrl($url);


    if($lastEffectiveUrl==$url)
    {
        $url_data=file_get_contents($url);

        $domHtmlStr = new DOMDocument();
        $domHtmlStr->loadHTML($url_data);
        $metaTag = $domHtmlStr->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        foreach($metaTag as $metaTagVal)
        {
          if($metaTagVal->getAttribute("http-equiv")=="refresh")
          {
            $metaContent = $metaTagVal->getAttribute("content");
            break;
          }
        }

        if($metaContent!="")
        {
         $metaContentSplit=explode("URL=",$metaContent);
         $lastEffectiveUrl1 = getLastEffectiveUrl(trim($metaContentSplit[1]));
         echo "Final URL : ".$lastEffectiveUrl1;
        }

    }

?>
```

Source : http://codeaid.net/php/get-the-last-effective-url-from-a-series-of-redirects-for-the-given-url

Note : http://performance.ikoo.com/geo_tracking_redirect.html?a=CD441&program_id=1304274 is not loading!

Comment: No, the url that I mentioned in description, is taking sometime but redirect

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now it'd not working for link :  http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=5477&id=129196

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code for [this](http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=5477&id=129196) url..

Which returns redirected url for tracking url..

```
$url = "http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=5477&id=129196";    
stream_context_set_default(array('http' => array('method' => 'HEAD')));
print_r(get_headers($url, 0));
$larr = get_headers($url, 1)["Location"];

$loc = is_array($larr) ? array_pop($larr):$larr;
echo $loc."</pre>";
$domain = parse_url($loc, PHP_URL_HOST);
print_r($domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Goutte can do this for you.
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

It will follow HTTP 3xx redirects and also `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tags.

Sample code:

```
$client= new \Goutte\Client();
$url="http://www.awin1.com/awclick.php?mid=5477&id=129196";
echo $client->request("GET",$url)->getUri();
```